# Having a number in a textsearch string stops it being found

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Mongo text search stemming is not working for text with a number attached.

i.e

DB:

```
{"fieldA": "value"},
{"fieldA": "value1"},
```

Search is:

```
{"fieldA": "value"}
```

returns 1 object

```
{"fieldA": "value"}
```

but not

```
{"fieldA": "value1"}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Stemming is based on language heuristics for common root forms (in particular, using the [Snowball stemming library](https://snowballstem.org/demo.html)). Mixed alphanumeric text like `value1` does not fit any common language rules, so will only be indexed in the original form (there is no root word or stem). If you want to ignore the numeric values, one approach would be to strip these from the source strings and save into a separate field for the text index. If you don't actually need language stemming (i.e. only search for `value`), you could use a regular index instead of a text index.

Answer (score 0):

You're not missing anything, it just seems mongo does not stem numbers from a string.

A neat little trick to see how mongo stem words is to run this:

```
db.collection.find({$text: {$search: 'sleeping1'}}).explain();
```

in the results under winning plan we can view the parsedTextQuery JSON:

```
{
      "terms": [
        "sleeping1"
      ],
      "negatedTerms": [],
      "phrases": [],
      "negatedPhrases": []
    }
```

now if we run the same query but with "sleeping" instead:

```
{
  "terms": [
    "sleep"
  ],
  "negatedTerms": [],
  "phrases": [],
  "negatedPhrases": []
}
```

mongo is not quite there yet when it comes to text indexing.